# Date doesnt update when I add $inc operator to update data in node, mongodb application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, updates, increment

The date attached to a  data doesn't update/show current date when the data is updated.

I'e tried this but only the data is updated

```
findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
 {$inc: {quantity: req.body.quantity, sold: req.body.sold}},
 {$set: {created_at: new Date()}},
 (callback)=>{})
});
```

And when i try to put the the code for date before the `$inc` operator code i.e -

```
findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
 {$set: {created_at: new Date()}},
 {$inc: {quantity: req.body.quantity, sold: req.body.sold}},
 (callback)=>{})`
```

it works/show updated time but the `$inc` code doesnt work. Seems like i can only have one of them present in in update route and i need both to work

Here's the code

```
router.put('/stocks/:id', (req, res)=>{
Stocks.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
 {$inc: {quantity: req.body.quantity, sold: req.body.sold}},
 {$set: {created_at: new Date()}},

 (err, updatedStock)=>{
    if(err){
        res.redirect('/stocks');
    }
    else{
        res.redirect('/stocks'); // + req.params.id
    }
})
});
```

I expect the the data along with the date and time to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter in mongoose [Model.findByIdAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) is used for options.

You would need to modify your call to something like this:

```
router.put('/stocks/:id', (req, res)=>{
Stocks.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
 {
   $inc: {quantity: req.body.quantity, sold: req.body.sold},
   $set: {created_at: new Date()}
 },

 (err, updatedStock)=>{
    if(err){
        res.redirect('/stocks');
    }
    else{
        res.redirect('/stocks'); // + req.params.id
    }
})
});
```

Hope this helps :)